# How to pass column value to 'nested' subquery

Tags: mysql

Explanations:
Basically it's a 2D grid.

Goal: Calculate the sum of the bonuses (green cells) in a certain range (red square) around specific locations (blue cells).

[image]

NB: coordinates can be negative.

Blue cells are specific locations, and are in the T1 table.

Table T1 :

```
x, y
```

Green cells are bonuses with different values at specific coordinates and are in the T2 table.

Table T2 :

```
x, y, bonus
```

To calculate the final bonus, SUM the green bonuses (LIMIT 3 ORDERED BY BONUS DESC) from T2 which are within a square of size 7 by 7, centred on a blue cell from T1.

In this example, the answer (calculated bonus) for this blue cell would be 20+15+10.

---

I'm kind of new to the joins and subqueries in MySQL, so it's really complicated for me to explain you what the problem is, so I'll show mostly the code.

Below is my query. This one works because I force coordinates in the subquery (see -10 and -100), but I need to replace these values -10 and -100 by c.x and c.y.

The problem is that I can't use 'c'.

I get the following error: Unknown column 'c.x' in 'where clause'.

---

```
SELECT 
    c.x, 
    c.y,
    (
        SELECT Sum(bonus) AS bonus
        FROM
        (
            SELECT bonus
            FROM t2
            WHERE Abs(-10 - x) <= 3 
            AND Abs(-100 - y) <= 3 
            ORDER BY bonus DESC
            LIMIT 3
        ) AS sub
    ) AS bonus
FROM t1 AS c
```

Then I tried with a CROSS JOIN, same problem.

```
SELECT
    c.x, 
    c.y
FROM t1 AS c
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT Sum(bonus) AS bonus
    FROM
    (
        SELECT bonus
        FROM t2
        WHERE Abs(-10 - x) <= 3 
        AND Abs(-100 - y) <= 3 
        ORDER BY bonus DESC
        LIMIT 3
    ) AS sub
) AS b
```

NB:

- It would work if the bonus query had NO subquery but I have to use one
  because I need a limit and the limit applies after the sum if you
  don't use a subquery.
- A solution would be to do it with multiple queries.
- I also tried with aliases but same problem.

Comment: @Strawberry I added some info. But it would be good to ask differently next time.

Comment: It would be good to provide the information requested.

Comment: @Strawberry Is that you who downvoted ?

Comment: @Strawberry If it's you it's kind of ridiculous at this point, I have here much more info than most of the question on SO have. I gave you the Tables, I explained what should be achieved, an example and its expected result. If you don't wanna help someone, just leave, you don't have to be rude.

Answer (score 0):

Then you might want to `JOIN` like

```
SELECT 
    c.x, 
    c.y, sub.bonus
FROM t1 AS c JOIN
    (
        SELECT Sum(bonus) AS bonus
            FROM t2
            WHERE Abs(-c.x - x) <= 3 
            AND Abs(-c.y - y) <= 3 
            ORDER BY bonus DESC
            LIMIT 3
        ) as sub ON c.Id = sub.Id;
```

Comment: oh my bad, I replaced the tables' names with '...' but there are actually 2 different tables. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @Ploppy, does it makes sense now. I mean the edit in answer.

Comment: The ids are different. I can't join.

Comment: @Ploppy, that's just an example. Just join with any common column b/w the tables

Comment: Nothing is in common, the query search for elements from T2 in certain range from given coordinates, which is the WHERE clause of the subquery. So what I should do if I understand you is to join ON this WHERE clause and I don't know if it is possible, I tried but I failed at it.

Comment: In the inline view, you have to select id, sum(bonus) in order to do a join against it.

Comment: @TGray can you please explain more in-depth, I don't understand.

Comment: Sure.  I don't want to take credit away from Rahul, though.  In the parenthetical select clause, it should read "SELECT Id, SUM(bonus)...GROUP BY Id" in order for the join  "ON c.Id = Sub.Id" to work.  An inline view (select in the from clause) is not the same as the table it's based on, so it doesn't inherit all of the columns of the base table.  It contains only those columns in the select statement.  So you can't join on something that is not in the inline view.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this will do what you want

```
SELECT 
    c.x, 
    c.y,
    bonus.bonus
FROM t1 AS c
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT Sum(bonus) AS bonus
        FROM
        (
            SELECT bonus
            FROM t2
            WHERE Abs(-c.x - x) <= 3 
            AND Abs(-c.y - y) <= 3 
            ORDER BY bonus DESC
            LIMIT 3
        ) AS sub
    ) AS bonus ON 1 = 1
```

Comment: This does not work, I get the same error : Unknown column 'c.x' in 'where clause'. I think that this error happens because it is in a subquery.